# Rspec, Paperclip, Fabrication, valid object without saving to filesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails 3.2 app with paperclip 3.2 and I have a model that has a required paperclip attachment(thumb).  How can I create valid objects without having the file saved to the filesystem or S3.  What I currently have is below but this saves to the filesystem on each run.  Is there a way to have a valid episode without uploading everytime?

### Model:

```
class Episode
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  has_mongoid_attached_file :thumb
  validates_attachment_presence :thumb
end
```

### Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Episode do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    Fabricate.build(:episode).should be_valid
  end
end
```

### Fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:episode) do
  thumb { File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fabricators', 'assets', 'thumb.jpg'))}
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this:

http://room118solutions.com/2011/05/25/stubbing-paperclip-during-testing/

for Paperclip 3.0:
There were some significant changes in Paperclip 3.0, you should now use something like this:

spec/support/stub_paperclip_attachments.rb

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
    def save
      @queued_for_delete = []
      @queued_for_write = {}
      true
    end

  private
    def post_process
      true
    end
  end

  # This is only necessary if you're validating the content-type
  class ContentTypeDetector
  private
    def empty?
      false
    end
  end
end
```