# Fabricate Paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, fabrication-gem

I'm trying to test my photo uploads with Fabricator and paperclip, but I'm having trouble using fabricator to create a paperclip object.

My current thought process is to include this module:
http://room118solutions.com/2011/05/25/stubbing-paperclip-during-testing/

After including, I should be able to fabricate on it??
Unfortunately, I don't quite know enough about Fabricator to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to test something related to upload logic, and your test suite does not include fabricating lot of objects with attachments, you can do this:

```
Fabricator(:fabricator_name) do
  image { File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fabricators', 'assets', 'image.jpg'))}
end
```

And place any small image named image.jpg to spec/fabricators/assets/ folder. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12677786/1102013) in question.